# c# while loop break

Tags: c#, while-loop

I was wondering if someone can help me.  I am very new to programming and this is my first time using stackoverflow.

I am looking at creating a while loop that ask the user for a their background and once the input is correct to break out of the loop. I could use break to exit out but I was trying to find another way.  My code so far is:

```
var background = "";

while (background != "M" || background != "W" || background != "R")
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + name + ", " + "Please pick a class: \n" +
                              "(M)age \n" +
                              "(W)arrior \n" +
                              "(R)ogue \n");
    var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
    if (readLine != null) background = readLine.ToUpper();

    if (background == "M")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome Mage " + name);            
    }
    else if (background == "W")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome Warrior " + name);                    
    }
    else if (background == "R")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome Rogue " + name);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with break?

Comment: @JJJ - in general, control structures with one entry and one exit are easier to understand, related to the single entry/single exit rule.

Comment: It just seem wrong to me when I made a condition which should of stopped the loop and I still had to use a break to get out it.  What was the point in having the condition in the first place.  Ok my condition was wrong and that why I was stuck.

Comment: Since you already have an accepted answer, I'll just mention that this seems like a natural fit for a do/while loop to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"||" is "or". Your `while` expression will always be true, because it is always true that background is not "M", *or* it is not "W", *or* it is not "R".

With "or", all three of the checks there must be false for the whole expression to be false, but at least two of those "!=" subexpressions *must* always be true at any time. If `background` is "M", it can't be "W" or "R".

```
    while (background != "M" || background != "W" || background != "R")
```

What you want is "&&", meaning "and": You want to continue the loop while background is not "M" *and* background is not "W", etc.

```
    while (background != "M" && background != "W" && background != "R")
```

Comment: That make's sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SerbjitKang if this answered your question please make sure you make this the accepted answer

Comment: @SerbjitKang My pleasure. Tyler Gaffaney's way of writing the loop is a good idea too, but I thought it would be helpful to understand where yours went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 'flag' to specify if the loop should break or not will work in your case.

```
var background = "";
bool breakLoop = false;

    while (!breakLoop)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + name + ", " + "Please pick a class: \n" +
                          "(M)age \n" +
                          "(W)arrior \n" +
                          "(R)ogue \n");
        var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
        if (readLine != null) background = readLine.ToUpper();

        if (background == "M")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Mage " + name);
            breakLoop = true;
        }

        else if (background == "W")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Warrior " + name);
            breakLoop = true;
        }

        else if (background == "R")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Rogue " + name);
            breakLoop = true;
        }

        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to create a list of accepted responses and check if the user input is in that list.

```
var name = "Bob";
var validTypes = new List<string> {"M", "W", "R"};
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {name}, please pick a class" +
                       "\n(M)age" +
                       "\n(W)arrior" +
                       "\n(R)ogue" +
                       "\n");
    var charType = Console.ReadLine();

    if (validTypes.Contains(charType.ToUpper()))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid class letter");
    }
```

Comment: Note that this snippet does not take into account any exception handling should a user input something that can't be made ToUpper(), it's just for example purposes of course.